# Mark Javacard applet as implicit selectable (default applet) after install

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I'm looking for a way to mark an applet as the implicit selectable/"selected by default" applet after it already has been uploaded and installed on a [Global Platform](http://www.globalplatform.org/)/[JCOP 2.4.2 R1](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/authentication/series/A700X_FAMILY.html) system (for starters in the NXP JCOP Tools
Java Card Simulation).

The applet has been installed without the `-d` parameter in the JCOP shell:

```
cm> install -i a000100201100001  -q C9#() a000100201100000 a000100201100001
 => 80 E6 [...]
 90 00
```

after that the state is

```
Card Manager AID   :  A000000003000000
Card Manager state :  OP_READY

    Application:  SELECTABLE (--------) A000100201100001
    Load File  :      LOADED (--------) A0000000035350   (Security Domain)
     Module    :                        A000000003535041
    Load File  :      LOADED (--------) A000100201100000
     Module    :                        A000100201100001
```

The desired result is

```
Card Manager AID   :  A000000003000000
Card Manager state :  OP_READY

    Application:  SELECTABLE (-----D--) A000100201100001
    Load File  :      LOADED (--------) A0000000035350
    [...]
```

That's the output when the applet is installed with the `-d|--default` parameter.
I suspect changing this attribute is somehow done via the STORE-DATA command in the card manager applet but haven't been able to find the exact, detailed command (structure) - not even the tag that needs to be modified.

Comment: I've settled for a little makeshift workaround that intercepts the jcop shell output, looks for the install commands and keeps them in a separate list to issue the appropriate `delete` and `install -d` commands when a button is clicked. Patchy,Buggy&Ugly as can be but for the moment sufficient....

Comment: I don't understand the issue I guess. You can simply instruct JCOP to issue -d. Go to Run Configurations, then Package Upload, doubleclick the applet and change the privileges. Hah, spelled "priviledges, -d for that as well :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on cards - not all of them seem to support making an applet default after installation. But you can use the open source [GlobalPlatform](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatform#get-it-now) tool for Java that has `--make-default <AID>` option:

```
java -jar gp.jar --make-default A000100201100001
```

IIRC JCOP was one of the cards that actually supported it.

Comment: Huh? Wow. I stand corrected. Note that the Applet should be programmed in such a way that the file system (if any) is in the correct state if it is set to default (afterwards).